# How to get a static final property from a property file with spring boot

Tags: mysql, sql, spring-boot, properties, spring-data-jpa

I've a spring boot project working on mysql DB. To encrypt some column I used the mysql function aes_encrypt, aes_decrypt and I stored my secret_key in a property file. Now to make some query on db I've to use in the crudrepository some native query like this.

```
@Query(value = "select * from a_table at where AES_DECRYPT(at.column1, +StaticClass.KEY+)= 'ABC'", nativeQuery = true)
public List<A>findByParameter();
```

I get this error "The value for annotation attribute Query.value must be a constant expression"

But the property KEY is already a FINAL property instantiate in this way

```
public class StaticClass {

static {

    Properties prop = new Properties();
    InputStream input;
    try {
        input = new FileInputStream("application.properties");
        prop.load(input);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        logger.error("Error");
    }
    if(prop.getProperty("property1")==null) {
        logger.error("property not found");
    }

    KEY=prop.getProperty("property1", "");
}

public static final String KEY;
```

One solution is to store the key in the code, but i need to keep the key in a property file. How can solve this problem?

Updated 1
I tried also in this way

```
public class StaticClass {

@Value(value="property1")
public static final String KEY;
}
```

Comment: Add `KEY: key` in application.yml and access it using `@Value(value="${KEY}")` annotation.

Comment: I tried already but it says "The blank final field KEY may not have been initialized"

Comment: Can you post your updated code?

Comment: Try adding `@Configuration` annotation above the class

Comment: nope, same problem "The blank final field KEY may not have been initialized". I don't think this is the way, i believe you can't inject some value in a static final property.

Comment: May I know why you want it to be `static`? If you don't use `static` it will work fine

Answer (score 0):

You can create for this constants like below.

```
   public enum Foo {

    FOO("app.foo"), FOO_BAR("app.foo.bar");

    private Environment environment;

    private final String propertyKey;

    Foo(String propertyKey) {
        this.propertyKey = propertyKey;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return environment.getProperty(propertyKey);
    }

    private void setEnvironment(Environment environment) {
        this.environment = environment;
    }

    @Component
    private static class EnvironmentInjector {

        @Autowired
        private Environment environment;

        @PostConstruct
        private void postConstruct() {
            for (Foo fT : EnumSet.allOf(Foo.class))
                fT.setEnvironment(environment);
        }
    }
}
```

then you can use like this :

`Foo.FOO.getValue()`

```
@Query(value = "select * from a_table at where AES_DECRYPT(at.column1, +Foo.FOO.getValue()+)= 'ABC'", nativeQuery = true)
public List<A>findByParameter();
```